# Any reason to use Mouse click vs Keyboard to post?

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox that posts data with js keyboard enter event. Is there any practical reason not to do this and instead create a submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people will expect to see a Submit button to click with the mouse.  Some people are mouse users, others are keyboard users - why not provide both methods?

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is disabled in the browser, the form won't be able to be submitted without a submit button.

Comment: You can hit enter in a form with javascript disabled, and it will be submitted, at least in firefox 3.5 and ie8...